# Pejorative Nickname Reference

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a single word or very short phrase to describe the act of contemptuously referring to someone by using a diminutive "nickname", with which that person is not normally associated?

For example, referring to Henry Wadsworth Longfellow as Hank Longfellow?
Or William Penn as Billy Penn?

Comment: Well you are belittling, patronizing, or infantilizing that person -- but there are plenty of ways to do those things besides using a nickname.

Comment: If you can effect enough sarcasm or humor, ***"affectionately called" or "affectionately known as***" are frequently used to share a less than favorable nickname that people use for a figure or thing.

Comment: I can't see how "Billy" or "Hank" is pejorative in the OP's examples.

Answer (score 1):

[Epithet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epithet) sort of works.  It doesn't necessarily imply disparagement, but is often used in that sense:

> a :  a characterizing word or phrase accompanying or occurring in
>   place of the name of a person or thing
>
> b :  a disparaging or abusive
>   word or phrase

Comment: There is also the (old-fashioned and never common) verb form, *epithetize*. It's in the OED, with an example that fits the OP's situation, but the latest appropriate example I can find in Google Books is a snippet from the 1970s: *...whose presumed power over the numerous holders of the cabinet portfolio led the Colonial Reformers such as Charles Buller to **epithetize** him as Mr. Oversecretary or Mr. Mothercountry.* — [Bengal: Past and Present Volume 93, p. 57](https://books.google.com/books?id=_pC1AAAAIAAJ&q=epithetize&dq=epithetize&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3ipLprK_RAhXJZCYKHZTtDZQQ6AEIJzAC)

Comment: Although this doesn't imply the specifically *diminutive* nature of the OP's examples (Hank for Henry, Billy for William)...I doubt there's anything closer, though.

Answer (score 0):

***colloquially known as***

... is a pretty common way of sharing a nickname that might not be fit for publication or all occasions.

... especially as the word "colloquially" is understood.

[dictionary.com definition of colloquially](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/colloquially)

> 1, 2. Colloquial, conversational, informal refer to types of speech or to usages not on a formal level.
>
> Colloquial is often mistakenly used with a connotation of disapproval, as if it meant “vulgar” or “bad” or “incorrect” usage, whereas it is merely a familiar style used in speaking and writing. Conversational refers to a style used in the oral exchange of ideas, opinions